# Raspberry PI Bullseye and Buster Pyinstaller multiple files not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyinstaller

I attempting to use pyinstaller to compile an executable file.  I have two python files, main.py and test.py. Python version is 3.9.

main.py:

```
import test

print("Hi")
test.test_func()
```

test.py:

```
def test_func():
    print("Test Func")
```

Running python3 main.py gives expected output:

```
Hi
Test Func
```

Runing

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

or
pyinstaller --onefile main.py test.py

gives the following output:

```
Hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    test.test_func()
AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'test_func'
[4102] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Tried this an older version of the Raspberry PI with Python3.7 and it works as expected.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone encounters this issue the problem having the test_func in test.py.

test.py is already a file in the python code base.  If file is re-named mytest.py issue no occurs